# How to reuse Thematic layer definitions in Mapinfo?

Tags: mapinfo, cartography, mapbasic

I have a map from table. Let the table be **TABLE1**. Now That I have created Thematic Map from **Column1** of this table. Again I executed the following query

```
Select * from TABLE1 where TABLE1.column1 ="someVal" into TABLE2
Add Map auto  Layer TABLE2
```

Now that new table has been created the old thematic layer **does not work**. Again I create new thematic layer from TABLE2 and execute following query

```
Select * from TABLE1 where TABLE2.column1 = "otherVal" into TABLE2. 
 Add Map auto  Layer TABLE2
```

Thus again thematic map I created is lost.

I have created buttons to execute these query but each time I click the button the thematic layer is lost. Is there any way that I could preserve the thematic layer and apply it to TABLE2 for **all select query** executed.

Actually the motive was to **use thematic map** that was created for **TABLE1**. But as the **points or value change in each selection** and **points of thematic layer remains constant** and lie in same initial coordinate the thematic layer becomes unusable.

> What is the right solution for reusing thematic layer in each Query?

Answer (score 1):

If you are doing this through the GUI and not via MapBasic then you can make use of the thematic template functionality to save a thematic template from the original thematic (TABLE1) and then apply it to subsequent query tables, you cannot do this using built in MapBasic functionality though.

Comment: Thanks for you answer Well I want to do this using mapbasic program